# Find a factorisation in a cubic field.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Take $\alpha$ a root of $x^3-7$ and consider $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. This is a pure cubic field. I am interested in the ideals which ramify. Since the discriminant here is $27\cdot7^2$, I have to look at the ideals generated by 3 and 7 in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, which is the ring of integers. Surely $(7)=(\alpha)^3$.

Now we consider $(3)$. I think I have to find $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$(3)=(3,\alpha+a)(3,\alpha+b)(3,\alpha+c).$$ Computing, I get a system of modular equation which solution is $a,b,c=2$. Thus $$(3)\supset(3,\alpha+2)(3,\alpha+2)(3,\alpha+2).$$ For the other inclusion, is there a better way or have I to find 3 in this product by hand? I think that not always is simple. And more, I am always sure that the ideals in the factorisation are of the form $(3,\alpha+a)$? Why not, for example, $(3,\alpha^2+a)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of Kummer's factorization theorem? This gives you the answer instantly. Since $x^2-7$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb Q$, we can take its reduction mod $3$ and reduce it into a product of irreducibles to get the prime factorization of $(3)$ in $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$: as polynomials in $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ we have

$$x^3-7=x^3+2=(x+2)^3$$

and therefore $(3)=\mathfrak p^3$ where $\mathfrak p=(3,\alpha+2)$.

Edit: You could also look at the "norm" function, it sends an ideal $I\subset\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ to the cardinality of $\Bbb Z[\alpha]/I$ (this is always finite if $I$ is nonzero since $\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ is the ring of integers of a number field). This norm is multilpicative with respect to products of ideals, and as a result, in general we have that if

$$I\subseteq J\text{ and } N(I)=N(J)\implies I=J.$$

Applied to our case, if you could show that

$$N((3))=N((3,\alpha+2)^3)=(N(3,\alpha+2))^3$$

(which is the same as showing that $N(3,\alpha+2)=3$), then it follows that the two ideals are equal.

Comment: No, I was not aware of this theorem, thank you! Are there other techniques to show it?

Comment: @Yecabel See my edit

Comment: We get $N(3,\alpha+2)=|\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/(3,\alpha+2)|=|\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^3-7,3,x+2)|=|\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x+2)|=3$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Yecabel Looks good, nice!

Comment: You need to be a bit more careful. Modular factorization of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ works as prescribed if one the conditions A) the factors are all simple, B) the powers of $\alpha$ form an integral basis.

Comment: To give an example consider the case of $\alpha=\sqrt5$, $p=2$. The minimal polynomial $x^2-5\equiv(x-1)^2\pmod2$, but the rational prime $2$ does not ramify even though there is a repeated factor. This is because to get an integral basis we need $\theta=(1+\sqrt5)/2$ with minimal polynomial $x^2-x-1$ that is irreducible modulo two. In fact, this shows that two is inert in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$.